# Seeing a flashing laser dot

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I want to determine if a laser dot (or dots) are anywhere in the field of view of my camera. I can flash the laser in synchronization with the camera frames so the dots are present only on alternate frames. This method should give 100% confidence that any visible dots are from my laser after processing 4 or 5 frames.

My first project involves determining if the laser dot (or dots) are visible at all, and the second project would be to determine the pixel separation (H and V) of two or more dots.

I would like to be able to run the software on a Raspberry pi.

Does anyone have any experience doing something like this?  Would anyone be interested in helping me accomplish these projects?

Answer (score 0):

I dont get why you got downvotes... 
Yes, you are able to realize this. Depending on your programming skills, i would choose python or C++. Following stuff is pretty simple but only works if your camera isnt moving. The Keyword is: Differenceimage

**Algorithm**
You could simply do some difference pictures. Do a picture without laserdot, activate the laser and do a picture with laserdot. You simply just look for the pixels that changed to the color of your laser.

This will work in python, but it wont be as fast as doing it with C++. In Python i would use OpenCV. In C++ i would work with Video4Linux2, because its extremly fast doing stuff like this.

**Get Better Results**
If you want to get better results, you could use a "red filter" (if you use a red laser). Just buy a cheap one on any shop and glue it on your camera. This will make it much more easy to find the laser dot.

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I was planning on using a red filter.  But the problem is that my camera and laser are moving.  I have asked the OpenCV crowd, but have had no answers so far.